# Can derived class be singleton?

Tags: c++

I need to have some common functionality while the derived class needs to have singleton behavior. 
For example:

```
class A
{
//common file functions 
}
class B : public A
{
//Needs to be singleton . since there is specific file of this class
}
class C : public A
{
//Needs to be singleton. There is also specific file of this class
}
```

Is it ok to make derived class as singleton or a composition is good idea in this case?

Comment: I think there are ways to avoid singletons. While they are very easy to use, many consider them to be a code smell.

Comment: What do you mean by "there is a specific file for this class?" Does the class modify and retrieve data for a specific file, or are you stating that there is a specific C++ source file defining the behavior in those derived classes?

Comment: Without a little more information about the derived classes I'm afraid it will be difficult to give you any advice, other than singletons are usually bad design.

Comment: @Michael  I've seem class hierarchies with a [null object pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/null-object-pattern.html).  The class for the null was a singleton, which reduced the memory footprint.  Singletons, however, aren't strictly required for the null object pattern.

Comment: @GregBurghardt  yes class modify and retrieve data for specific file. Basically A has all the XML query/retrieving functions. Class B and C associated with different XML files.  B and C  has their own XML files and needs to be singleton to avoid multiple read access to those files. XML reading code will be required by both classes.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a factory instead.  A factory can choose to recycle instances, so essentially creating the same "singleton" without the singleton pattern.  Your program though absolutely should *not* treat instances as if they were singletons if you do it this way, as it may change later.

Also please don't make your factory itself a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

No that sounds like a bad idea.

Absent of any `B` or `C` specific behaviour, it sounds like you want

```
int main()
{
    A B(<B's params>);
    A C(<C's params>);

    // use `B` and `C`
}
```